# What is the List entity count(x/50) in Luis apart from Entity count?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

In LUIS AI tool there is a "list entity count" shown. What is it actually?

Comment: Please, Show what you seen in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but here's what I think you're asking about.

The List entity count (x/50) is the *total amount of list entities you can have in your LUIS model*. This limit is separate from the other types of entities; Prebuilt, Simple, Hierarchical (and their children) and Composite entities. You can only have a combination of up to 30 of these entities.

The reason why these 50 don't contribute to your limit of 30 is that these entities *aren't* machine learned. They're recognized through regex.

Each list entity can contain up to 20,000 items.

You can find more information on Entities in LUIS [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-entity-types).

Comment: I am sorry my question was silly!!! I seriously didnt notice the documentation for list entity.. Thanks a lot